# move and make directory

Tags: shell, mv, mkdir

I know its a big classical but I didn't found the exact situation that concerns me

I need a `mkdir`+`mv` command that can be invoked like that :

```bash
mvdir /home/user/Documents/irs.pdf /mnt/work/45/223/insight/irs1970.pdf
```

Exactly like a normal `mv` command works, just with a creation of path instead of a `no such file or directory`

Considering that `work/45/223/insight/` doesn't exist and need to be created

All other command that I've found can't be invoked like that, needs some more informations, need to distinguish the path and file ourself, or something

Attempt: `mkdir -p /mnt/work/45/223/insight && mv /home/user/Documents/irs.pdf /mnt/work/45/223/insight/irs1970.pdf`

Comment: If you have a list of commands that would implement what you need you could write your own script

Comment: Exactly. But all the script that I've found leads to a command that have not this form

Comment: Ignore scripts for a moment. How would you do this if you were typing it at the command line?

Comment: `mkdir -p /mnt/work/45/223/insight && mv /home/user/Documents/irs.pdf /mnt/work/45/223/insight/irs1970.pdf`

Comment: You might find that `/mnt/work/45` exists, in which case creating the whole name again will fail. Check `man mkdir` for the `-p` option. Also consider defining a function in your .profile when you have tested your commands: better than either an alias or a script.

Comment: So it needs to a special `mkdir` command who can just complete the missing path, who not fail too. My command doesn't work as is because it's two commands. I need one that make the work, who distinguish himself the path and the filename, like `mv`, just with a creation of path instead of an error. Sure I will consider to write in hard the function when I will find one that fulfill the need

Comment: @aaa include your attempt at the script. Otherwise it is asking for code with no attempts to resolve your issue yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt in the question is a fair stab. Here's how I would consider approaching it

```bash
#!/bin/sh
src=$1
dst=$2

if [ ! -d "$dst" ]
then
    dir=${dst%/*}                   # dir path
    [ "$dir" = "$dst" ] && dir=.    # but had no dir

    mkdir -p "$dir"                 # create path
fi
mv "$src" "$dst"                    # move file
```

Save this as your `mvdir` somewhere in your `$PATH`, and make it executable.

It would be possible to extend this script to handle multiple sources but I haven't done that here

Answer (score 0):

It's not the right answer but I still couldn't find something that will do the job

So instead I did a workaround, in two time, but who permit me to use the normal capacity of `mv`. I recreated the path totally, then I moved the file

```bash
find /mnt -type d -print0 | while read -d $'\0' i; do mkdir -p /home/user/Documents$i; done
mv /home/user/Documents/irs.pdf /mnt/work/45/223/insight/irs1970.pdf
```

Not ideal, but, well