# Move all PDF files to a separate directory that doesn't exist beforehand

Tags: files, mv

I am writing a simple method to mass move files and have attempted two approaches:

```
#(1)
find . -name '*.pdf' | xargs -I{} mkdir pdfs; mv {} pdfs 

#(2)
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec mv {} pdfs \+
```

The first approach surprisingly worked 'sometimes', however, after deleting the folder with the pdfs a few times and returning the pdfs to the parent directory, it suddenly stopped working.

It produces the following error:

```
mv: rename {} to pdfs: No such file or directory
xargs: unterminated quote
```

Whereas the second approach gives the following error:

```
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
```

Update:

I got it working with:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec mv "{}" pdfs \;
```

However, If I wanted to create the directory and move files in one line, this wont work, for example:

```
find . -name '*.csv' -exec mkdir -p csvs && mv "{}" csvs \;
```

> find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"

How to implement directory creation and move?

Comment: You might want to `man 1 find` and read the entries on `-exec` closely. Hint: the position of `{}` matters.

Comment: See: [understanding-the-exec-option-of-find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)

Comment: @Jetchisel I have looked at the document and attempted: `find . -name '*.csv' -exec bash -c 'mkdir csvs' bash 'mv {} csvs' \;` however this seems to recursively create the final and so move is never completed.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to get `bash -c 'mkdir csvs'` to only execute once?

Comment: `find -exec <command> \;` always executes `command` once for each of its matches. Why not: `mkdir foo; find . -name bar -exec mv -t foo {} \;`?

Comment: @StefanvandenAkker What about file names with white spaces, these won't get moved. I have attempted: `mkdir csvW; find . -name '*.csv' -print0 -exec bash -c $'\0' mv -t csvW {} \;` based on your interpretation, but the separator does not seem to work.

Comment: `-exec mv -t csvW {} +` is completely robust. You are needlessly complicating things and breaking support for arbitrary file names. See also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Comment: (However, the `-t` option to `mv` is a GNU extension; it is available on most Linuxes, but on other systems commonly requires you to separately install the GNU userspace utilities.)

Comment: @tripleee that would explain why I get errors when using `-t`, and likely what caused my previous comment.

Comment: @tripleee Although, when I attempt the following `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.csv' -type f -exec mv csvW {} \+`, I get that the .csv file `is not a directory`, am I mis-specifying something?

Comment: Without `-t` you can't do that; you are saying to move `csvW` and all the other files onto the last found file. Try instead `find ... -exec sh -c 'mv "$@" "$0"' csvW {} +`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
$ touch foo.pdf white\ space.pdf
$ ls
 foo.pdf  'white space.pdf'
$ mkdir pdfs && \
    find . -path ./pdfs -prune \
    -o -name '*.pdf' -exec mv {} pdfs/ \;
$ tree
.
└── pdfs
    ├── foo.pdf
    └── white space.pdf
```

1. This creates directory `pdfs` and only continues if successfully created.
2. This finds all files that end in `.pdf` while making sure it does not match the files it already moved to the `pdfs` directory (the `-path pdfs -prune` part skips files in this directory).
3. This *does* execute `mv` once for every match. Use `mv -t pdfs/ {} \+` (GNU extension) for performance.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your case is really this easy (files ending in .pdf), a simple

```
mv -- **/*.pdf pdfs/
```

would do.

For zsh, that recursive glob `**` is enabled by default, for bash you will have to enable it first, using `shopt -s globstar`.

I suspect your find invocation might be slightly more complicated in reality. But especially if you're using zsh, the extended globbing capabilities of your shell are quite capable and often save you the headache of remembering the right magic find arguments that work every time ;)

Answer (score 2):

The unquoted `;` separates the `mv` command from the `find` command so that cannot ever have worked.

The simplest solution by far is to create the destination directory before running `find`. If you don't want to keep an empty directory, you can `rmdir` it afterwards; this will fail if the directory contains any files.

If you have GNU `mv`, it has a `-t` option which lets you conveniently name the destination directory before the files you want to move so that you can say

```
mkdir pdfs
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec mv -t pdfs {} +
rmdir pdfs || true
```

If you don't have `mv -t`, try something like

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'mv "$@" "$0"' pdfs {} +
```

where we shamelessly use the "zeroth" parameter to `sh -c` for passing in the destination directory name separately from the argument list proper `"$@"`. (Conventionally this "zeroth" argument would contain the shell's name, but since that's not useful for anything here and the string has to contain something anyway, we can pull off a bit of a hack so we don't have to process the argument list.)

```
find ... -exec mv {} pdfs \;
```

works but is somewhat inefficient, as it runs a separate `mv` command for each found file. The `+` terminator to `-exec` says to run a single subprocess for as many files as possible (similarly to `xargs`) but requires the `{}` token to be last.

Comment: `find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'dir=$1; shift; mv "$@" "$dir"' sh pdfs {} +` isn't that much more to write... Or hmm, `dir=pdfs find . -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'mv "$@" "$dir"' sh {} +`?

Answer (score 0):

One way, using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727288/12574):

```
touch foo.pdf white\ space.pdf $'new\nline.pdf'
find . -name '*pdf' -print0 | rename -n -0 's|[^/]+\.pdf$|./pdfs/$&|ms'
```

Drop `-n` when attempts are satisfactory.

Comment: The `find -print0` and `xargs -0` options are also GNU extensions, and not standard.

Comment: @tripleee, not standard, but widely supported, e.g. by [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1)), [Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/find-1.html) and Busybox.

Comment: @tripleee, they are there on my Mac.

Comment: Duh, you're right ... Wonder when that changed. Still `rename` is a portability problem because there are multiple utilities with that name, with different behavior, syntax, and options.

Comment: It's long explained in the linked post

Answer (score 0):

Given you're moving files into a subdirectory `pdfs` I wonder if you're really only considering files in the current directory.

If so then a simple wildcard would suffice - but you would need to create the directory separately:

```
mkdir -p pdfs && mv -f *.pdf pdfs
```

I have [written a script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/726469/100397) for a previous [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/726431/100397) that merges these two operations in a slightly more robust manner.